# Question 1.17 from Fulton's Algebraic Curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties, multivariate-polynomial

I have been reading Fulton's Algebraic curves, chapter 1.3. The chapter starts by proving some properties about the ideal of a set of points for which the polynomials in that ideal vanish. This is denoted $I(X) \subseteq K[x_1, \dots , x_n]$ where $X \subseteq \mathbb A^n(K)$, $K$ a field.

Then I started working on the following question ($1.17$) and I feel a bit uncertain:

> (a) Let $V$ be an algebraic set in $\mathbb A ^n (K)$. Let $P \in \mathbb A^n(K) \setminus V$ be a point not in $V$.  Show that there is a polynomial $F \in K[X_1, \dots, X_n]$ such that $F(Q)=0$ for all $Q\in V$, but $F(P)=1$.
> (Hint: $I(V) \neq I(V \cup \{P\})$

The hint seems to suggest that I take some polynomial that vanishes on $V$, but not on $P$. Which is indeed what I want. So we should take some $G\in I(V)$ such that $G \not \in I(V \cup \{P\}) $. Since $G$ does not vanish at $P$, we know that $G(P) \neq 0$. Is it really as simple as now taking $$ F(X_1, \dots, X_n):=\frac{1}{G(P)}G(X_1, \dots, X_n) \quad ?$$

> (b)
> Let $P_1, \dots ,P_r$ be distinct points in $\mathbb A^n(K)$,  not in an
> algebraic set $V$. Show that there are polynomials $F_1, \dots, F_r \in I (V)$ such that $F_i (P_j )= 0$ if $i \neq j$ , and $F_i (P_i ) = 1$.

(Hint: Apply (a) to the union of V and all but one point.)

Here we generalise the result from question (a) to form an orthonormal basis of polynomials. My gut feeling is screaming " use induction on the amount of points $r$", but this is not what the hint is saying, I think.

**Base case:** $r=1$ this follows from (a) since indeed $F(P)=1$, but there are no other points to check so the other condition holds trivially.

**Induction Hypothesis** Suppose now that there are distinct points $P_1, \dots, P_m$ for some $m\in \mathbb N$,   such that for  $1\leq i,j \leq m$ there are $F_1, \dots, F_m \in I (V)$ with $F_i (P_j )= 0$ if $i \neq j$ , while $F_i (P_i ) = 1$.

We will now make the **inductive step**
Now suppose  that there are distinct points $P_1, \dots, P_{m+1}$. We now need to construct a final polynomial that evaluates to zero  for all the prior points and to $1$ for $P_{m+1}$. I am stumped. Maybe I should instead use the hint, but I do not know how.

> (c) With $P_1, \dots ,P_r$ and $V$ as in (b), and $a_{ij}\in K$ for $1 \leq i , j \leq r$ , show that there are
> $G_i \in I (V)$ with $G_i (P_j )=a_{ij}$ for all $i$ and $j$ .
> (Hint: Consider $\sum_{j}a_{ij}F_j$ .)

For this question we consider, as the hint suggests:
$$ G_i= \sum_{k=1}^ra_{ik} F_{k}$$
Where question (b) gives us that $F_1, \dots, F_r \in I (V)$ such that $F_k (P_j )= 0$ if $k \neq j$ , and $F_k (P_k ) = 1$.

Observe then that
$$ G_i(P_j):=\sum_{k=1}^r a_{ik}F_k(P_j)= a_{ij} $$
Since the only nonzero term in the sum is where $k=j$.

**EDIT.** as pointed out in the comments, I tricked myself with the summation variable. I changed the indices.

Comment: Part a) should be correct. Using induction in b) might work, but you could also construct the Polynomial in question directly. In Part c) you are almost there, but you tricked yourself with the index in the sum.

Comment: (c). I see where  I tricked myself. I should use a different summation variable. I will edit this!

Comment: Well, you first put in $P_j$ and then plug in the definition of $G_i$, which is a sum over $j$. But the input of the $F_j$s is supposed to be the same for every Summand! To see what I mean, calculate $G_i(P_k)$ instead.

Comment: Rookie mistake. I remember making this mistake too in my first year. Oh well, thanks a bunch :) Appreciate it.

Comment: Haha, glad to be of help! No one is immune to trovial mistakes, so keep it up!

Comment: Love the intentional typo.

Comment: For (b) I was thinking about linear terms of the form (x_1-p_1) where $p_1$ is the first coordinate of $P_1$, then I simply take the product of all of those and normalise. Or am I overthinking? My biggest problem with this would be the notation...

Comment: Yup, I had the same idea. And yeah. Let’s pretend the typo was intentional (:

Comment: We define for each $P_k=(p_1, \dots, p_r)$ the polynomial $H_k:=(X_1-p_1)\dots (X_r-p_r)$. Then it seems I am interested in:
$$ F_i(X_1,\dots, X_r) =  \frac{1}{\prod_{k=1, k\neq i}^r H_k(P_i)} \prod_{k=1, k\neq i}^r H_k (X_1,\dots, X_r) $$

Comment: For (b), a finite union of algebraic sets is algebraic, and a point is algebraic (taking the defining polys $x_i-p_i$) so this sort of eases notation as you can use (a).

Comment: @NL1992 that was probably the intention. To take the union of $V$ with all but one point and then pull the desired polynomial out of a hat as in (a) - as this was literally the hint, which I now understand.  Bedankt!

Comment: That answers all of my questions, If nobody wants to claim the answer, I will post one myself later so the question is closed, but feel free to write the comment down in the answer section so I can thank you with my upvote :)

Answer (score 2):

My questions have been answered in the comments:

(a) is fine

(b) the finite union of algebraic sets is an again an algebraic set. Since points are algebraic sets we can take the union over all but one point $P_i$ with $V$ and apply (a), this gives the desired polynomial $F_i$ for each point $P_i$.

(c) Is fine as it is now, but I had made a summation error by plugging in $P_j$ while $j$ was also the summation variable.